# FileNotFoundException : AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

Im currently working on a project that will check if a certain .apk file is only installed on the device. If it is install, a button, when clicked, will open that application. now, my problem is reading the package name of the .apk for i can open in. i have seen a snippet here on how to read it.

```
String apkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/KiddieJam/Apps" + file_name;
                    System.out.println(apkPath);
                     PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

                     PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 
                                            PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                     Log.i("ActivityInfo", "Package name is " + info.packageName);
```

Im sure its working properly on other that might have used it also, but im having a problem and my logcat says FileNotFoundException : AndroidManifest.xml

> W/PackageParser(13839): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /mnt/sdcard/KiddieJam/Apps/Guitar_Hero_6_Apk.apk
>   /PackageParser(13839): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
>   W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
>   W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:486)
>   W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:454)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:401)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageArchiveInfo(PackageManager.java:1889)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at .ContentDetails.onCreate(ContentDetails.java:329)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   05-08 02:33:24.966: W/PackageParser(13839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The .apk file resides on the correct path. I just that .apk for testing purposes only.
any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Is `Guitar_Hero_6_Apk.apk` located at `/mnt/sdcard/KiddieJam/Apps/`? Try to verify it using ES Explorer app available on Google Play

Comment: Yes, it is located at the said path. BUT, i have created a application just like google play where i can download the .apk files. I just made  Guitar_Hero_6_Apk.apk as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it is due to "external" storage isolation...

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, include:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For example, somewhere in `MyApp.java`:

```
String PACKAGE_NAME = MyApp.class.getPackage().getName(); 
String KEY_DIRECTORY_SELECTED = PACKAGE_NAME + ".DIRECTORY_SELECTED";    

SharedPreference prefs = getSharedPreferences(PACKAGE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String apkPath = prefs.getString(KEY_DIRECTORY_SELECTED,
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()) + "/KiddieJam/Apps/" + file_name;

System.out.println(apkPath.trim());

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath.trim(),PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

Log.i("ActivityInfo", "Package name is " + info.packageName);
```

On the other hand, I may suspect you have forgotten the file separator to separate the filename: `/KiddieJam/Apps`. It should be `/KiddieJam/Apps/`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with your snippet it is working like charm for me,it returns the package name correctly as com.test

```
String apkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/download/Check/" + "test.apk";
            System.out.println(apkPath);
             PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

             PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageArchiveInfo(apkPath, 
                                    PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
             Log.i("call", "Package name is " + info.packageName);
```

Comment: No, i mean, the .apk file that im accessing is inside /mnt/sdcard/foldername. And i am getting those .apk file from a application that i also created that serves just like google play where you can download stuffs. isnt it possible?